# Error in frame() : figure margins too large

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to create a matrix of plots, but I want the upper left corner to be blank.  So I'm using:

```
frame()
```

To which R responds:

> Error in `frame()`: figure margins too large

I'm using the following two lines to create my layout:

```
plotIDs <- matrix(c(1:16), 4, 4, byrow = T);
layout(plotIDs, widths = c(0.5,1,1,1,1), heights = c(0.5,1,1,1,1));
```

and this gives me the following layout:

[image: 4 by 4 layout with first row and col at half height]

If I then issue `frame()` I get the above error.  What am I doing wrong?  I don't see any way to specify a height or a width for the `frame()` command (just an alias for `plot.new()`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The message means that the margins in the figure are too large and do not leave enough space for the plot.

Try reducing the margin:

```
op <- par(mar = par("mar")/2)
plot.new()  ## this is optional for this example
plot(1:10)
par(op)  ## tidy up to restore the default par setting
```

You can start with frame() or plot.new(), or just plot into the first panel.  Note you will need to consider what is an appropriate margin setting for each of your different panels, and fine-tune label sizes and so on.

For a totally blank panel, you might as well kill the margin completely:

```
op <- par(mar = rep(0, 4))
plot.new()
par(op)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can leave panels blank using layout by having a 0 in the matrix, so if you use 0:15 instead of 1:16 then the 1st panel will be blank without you needing to skip.  Of course you will neet to set margins and cex for the rest of the panels.

Comment: that's a more insightful answer than mine

Comment: @mdsumner, I don't know that mine is more insightful, it is a quick work around, but you gave more depth on what was actually causing the error and what to do about it (which with my work around is still needed for the actual plots).

Comment: True and now you've provided better commentary :)