# Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large (gam.check function)

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm having this error message when I try to see the diagnostic plots of the following model, with the function "gam.check":

```
mod <- zigam(PDS ~ as.factor(Site) + as.factor(Gear) + s(month, k=9, bs="tp"),
             offset(site.agressive$Effort), data=site.agressive,
             family=poisson, link="log")

    summary(mod$fit.gam)  
    plot(mod$fit.gam, all.terms=T, shade=T)
    gam.check(mod$fit.gam)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using RStudio? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050928/error-in-plot-new-figure-margins-too-large-scatter-plot for an example. In the plain old R GUI, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500697/error-in-frame-figure-margins-too-large.

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22error+in+plot.new%28%29%22, take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have not installed-loaded the mgcv package**

```
install.packages('mgcv')

library('mgcv')

mod <- zigam(PDS ~ as.factor(Site) + as.factor(Gear) + s(month, k=9, bs="tp"),
             offset(site.agressive$Effort), data=site.agressive,
             family=poisson, link="log")

summary(mod$fit.gam)  
plot(mod$fit.gam, all.terms=T, shade=T)
gam.check(mod$fit.gam)
```

**If you are using RStudio and you have installed-loaded the mgcv package**

In RStudio, try resizing the right side to increase the width of the windows. Now try to load the library ("mgcv"). Then run the code above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard problem when the Rstudio plot window is too small. Make it bigger and plot again.